# Work with widgets inside Qtabwidget

Tags: qt, pyside, qtabwidget

I see variant how program can work with `QWidget`,for example `QLabel`,`QEdit`,etc on C++. But i don't understand how can i work with other widgets on tab of tabwidget if i write programs with python & pyside?

I see variant with metaobject,read about variant with `QObject::child`,but i don't know right way for solving problem on python. I see variant with `qobject_cast`,but this function specific for C++ as i think. Sample code on C++:

try:

```
QTextEdit* edit = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(tabWidget->widget(index));
```

Comment: What's exact going wrong with accessing widgets? Do you use any form editor, or you create form programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not an expert of python, but did you try to use this:

```
yourObject = tabWidget.widget(index)
```

I guess it works with any type of object.